# show the result in a new screen (android)

Tags: android, eclipse

i have a app to calculate screen blend.. when the button is press the result is showed in the same screen..  i need to show the result after click the button in a new screen...

.java

public class MainActivity6 extends Activity {

```
double altura, largura, ratio, pixellarg, pixelalt, pixelportela, overlapperc, totallargpixel, totalpixelover, totalpixeloverfinal,numproj; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tela_blend);

    Button btncalcblend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncalcblend);
    btncalcblend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              EditText edtlargblend = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtlargblend);
              EditText edtaltblend = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtaltblend);
              EditText edtlargpixel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtlargpixel);
              EditText edtaltpixel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtaltpixel);
              EditText edtnumproj = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtnumproj);
              if (edtlargblend.getText().toString().length() <= 0){
                  edtlargblend.setError("Digite a largura");
                  edtlargblend.requestFocus();
                }else if (edtaltblend.getText().toString().length() <= 0){
                          edtaltblend.setError("Digite a altura");
                          edtaltblend.requestFocus();
                }else if (edtlargpixel.getText().toString().length() <= 0){
                          edtlargpixel.setError("Digite largura pixel");
                          edtlargpixel.requestFocus();
                }else if (edtaltpixel.getText().toString().length() <= 0){
                          edtaltpixel.setError("Digite altura pixel");
                          edtaltpixel.requestFocus();
                }else if (edtnumproj.getText().toString().length() <= 0){
                          edtnumproj.setError("Digite número projetores");
                          edtnumproj.requestFocus();


                }else {
                    largura = Double.parseDouble(edtlargblend.getText().toString());
                    altura = Double.parseDouble(edtaltblend.getText().toString());
                    pixellarg = Double.parseDouble(edtlargpixel.getText().toString());
                    pixelalt = Double.parseDouble(edtaltpixel.getText().toString());
                    numproj = Double.parseDouble(edtnumproj.getText().toString());

                    ratio = largura / altura;
                    totallargpixel = ratio * pixelalt;
                    totalpixelover = pixellarg * numproj;
                    totalpixeloverfinal = totalpixelover -totallargpixel;
                    pixelportela = totalpixeloverfinal / (numproj - 1);
                    overlapperc = (pixelportela /pixellarg) * 100;


                    EditText edttotalpixel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edttotalpixel);
                    edttotalpixel.setText(String.valueOf(totalpixeloverfinal));

                    EditText edtpixelportela = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtpixelportela);
                    edtpixelportela.setText(String.valueOf(pixelportela));

                    EditText edtoverlaperc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtoverlaperc);
                    edtoverlaperc.setText(String.valueOf(overlapperc));
                    edtoverlaperc.setText(String.format("%.2f", overlapperc));




                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edtnumproj.getWindowToken(),0);

                }

        }
    });

    Button btnvolt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnvoltar);
    btnvolt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Intent dtec = new
                    Intent(MainActivity6.this, MainActivity.class);
                    MainActivity6.this.startActivity(dtec);
                    MainActivity6.this.finish();

        }
        });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

    }
```

Comment: Unsolicited advice => createmoreeasilyreadvariables!

Comment: What do you mean by "a new screen"? Another Activity or a Dialog screen? You can have xml layouts and show them in a Dialog window inside your current activity.

Comment: `startActivity(intent);` like this ?

Answer (score 0):

set the activity and info:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, AActivityClass.class);
i.putExtra("Result1", result1);
i.putExtra("Result2", result2);
i.putExtra("Result3", result3);
startActivity(i);
```

get the info from the new activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Int result1 = intent.getIntExtra("Result1", 0);
Int result2 = intent.getIntExtra("Result2", 0);
Int result3 = intent.getIntExtra("Result3", 0);
```

Comment: but i need to show 3 different results..  can you give me a exemplo?

Comment: just add another putExtra with another name and result